# Postgresql triggers are not executed for Rails fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, triggers, fixtures

I have a trigger in my database that generates a random id "BEFORE INSERT".

For rails fixtures, used in the tests, they are not generated (triggers are in the db, I checked that).

Why that?

Comment: Offtopic: Why don't you use the SERIAL datatype to generate a number? Works for almost every case and is faster than a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Rails fixtures are not necessarily loaded in an order that satisfies database constraints, so the Rails solution is to turn them off while loading fixtures.

For example, with postgresql, here is some sql that Rails executes

```
 (2.0ms)  ALTER TABLE "admins" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "events" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
  ... insert all of the things
 (2.1ms) ALTER TABLE "admins" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "events" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

There is no way to use fixtures and get them to trigger db triggers on load. Using object builders like https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl will trigger db triggers.

In your case though, there is a better way to do what you need

```
alter table mytable add column random_column double precision DEFAULT random() NOT NULL
```

or if it is specifically the primary key column you want to randomize, you should use uuids.

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
CREATE TABLE some_table ( 
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    some_field character varying,
    other_table_id uuid REFERENCES other_table (id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL 
  );
```